# Como utilizar APIS HTTP GET?

Tags: javascript, api, http-request

Eu tenho uma API que realiza manipulação de objetos por meio de um link, os parâmetros são passados nesse link. Gostaria de saber como posso utiliza-lo ou criar um método em javascript para executar esse link.

Answer (score 2):

voce deve utilizar o XMLHttpRequest (ajax), ou fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) e passar a url que retorna o json na requisição.

No entanto o correto de passar parametros pelo GET é através da URI, os chamados 'Query Strings'

exemplo de uma classe em js:

```
class HttpRequest {

    static get (url, params = {}) {
        return HttpRequest.request("GET", url, params);
    }

    static delete (url, params = {}) {
        return HttpRequest.request("DELETE", url, params);
    }

    static post (url, params = {}) {
        return HttpRequest.request("POST", url, params);
    }

    static put (url, params = {}) {
        return HttpRequest.request("PUT", url, params);
    }

    static request(method, url, params={}){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

            ajax.open(method.toUpperCase(), url);

            ajax.onerror = event =>{
                reject(event);
            }

            ajax.onload = () => {
                let obj = {};
                try {
                    obj = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                } catch(e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(obj);
            };

            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            ajax.send(JSON.stringify(params));

        });
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Abraço!!